# How to solve this issue: Mousetrap is not defined error

Tags: javascript, mousetrap

I was trying to use the mousetrap.js library to enable certain keyboard commands on a website. I am using a `js injector extension` to inject a custom script and assign a function to an element.

I am embedding the library using this custom script.

```js
 var script100 = document.createElement('script');
   script100.setAttribute('src', 'https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/mousetrap/mousetrap.js?a4098');
   script100.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script100);
```

and using this script to bind the function copyDivToClipboard1() with the key `4`

```js
function copyDivToClipboard1() {
var range1 = document.createRange();
range1.selectNode(document.getElementById("box"));
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range1);
document.execCommand("copy");
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();};
Mousetrap.bind('4', function() { copyDivToClipboard1() ; });
```

I have also appended the script tag and inserted the function using this code

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.text = function copyDivToClipboard() {
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(document.getElementById("box"));
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
document.execCommand("copy");
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();};// use this for inline script
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: @craig wanted your help

Comment: Do you have Jquery? You can use mouseTrap when document ready, or you can use plain JS: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { //do work });`. Try to console.log Mousetrap inside

Comment: You've used Mousetrap before it's fully loaded, so you have to wait some delay for them to load. If you can control the backend parts (ruby or PHP, Nodejs), you just need to add `<script>` tag and it will work